# Double integral and Fubini

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Compute the integral $\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_{\pi/2-x}^{\pi}\cos(x+y)dxdy.$

Hello, my question is that I can solve it and we have that $I=-\pi/2-1.$ But, can be that the integral let a negative value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes an integral may be negative, and this one is so because $\cos(x+y)$ is negative in [a significant subset of that interval](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+z%3Dcos(x%2By)+for+x+%3D+0+to+pi%2F2,+y%3D0+to+pi).